# Aframe 3D Model not being rendered in Django project using static urls

Tags: django, aframe

I wish to render .obj and .mtl files in my Django project using Aframe. What I am trying to achieve is to take some user input such as "Apple" and then an apple object is rendered on the screen. Now whenever I hardcode my url for the static file, I get the rendered object. But when I pass url in the dictionary after appending the input to the url, the object is not being displayed. Query is for eg: Apple. My dictionary is of the following format:

```
dict = {0 :['education/Apple.obj','education/Apple.mtl']}
```

My views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader


def viser(request):
    template = loader.get_template('education/viser.html')
    context = {}
    context[0] = []
    context[0].append("'education/Apple.obj'")
    context[0].append("'education/Apple.mtl'")
    query = request.POST.get('inputquery', False)
    if query:      
        template2 = loader.get_template('education/DOG.html')
        return HttpResponse(template2.render(context, request))
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Hardcoded DOG.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
    {% load static %}        
    <a-entity obj-model="obj: {% static 'education/Apple.obj' %}; mtl: {% static 'education/Apple.mtl' %};" ></a-entity>         
  <a-entity position="0 70 150">
    <a-camera></a-camera>
  </a-entity>    
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamic DOG.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
    <a-sky color="#6EBAA7"></a-sky>
    {% load static %}
    {% for classlabel, value in context.items %}
        <a-entity obj-model="obj: {% static value.0 %}; mtl: {% static value.1 %};" ></a-entity>
    {% endfor %}
    <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls wasd-controls="acceleration:1000">
        <a-cursor color="yellow"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

One peculiar thing I observed during debugging was that whenever I tried a for loop in the hardcoded DOG.html file it did not let the browser render the object, but when I got rid of the for and the endfor tags, I got the rendered object. Is the for loop causing any problem in the program?

Peculiar DOG.html : Does not render the object

```
<a-scene>
    {% load static %} 
    {% for index, value in context.items %}
        <a-entity obj-model="obj: {% static 'education/Apple.obj' %}; mtl: {% static 'education/Apple.mtl' %};" ></a-entity>
    {% endfor %}
</a-scene>
```

Peculiar DOG.html after removal of for and endfor: Renders the object

```
<a-scene>
    {% load static %} 
    <a-entity obj-model="obj: {% static 'education/Apple.obj' %}; mtl: {% static 'education/Apple.mtl' %};" ></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: `value[0]` and `value[1]` are not valid in Django template language. Just use `value.0` and `value.1`.

Comment: I tried doing that but no 3D object (Apple) is being rendered on the browser. But when I hardcode the path in the static 'education/Apple.obj', it's getting rendered without any problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In that case, [edit] your question and show your updated code. I would also tryviewing the source of the rendered html in your browser, and see what the difference is between hardcoding the value and using the static tag.

Comment: @Alasdair I have updated the question as you asked sir. Any pointers, suggestions or help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting some of the basics of Django templates wrong. Before you try to get your `aframe` code or the `static` tag to work, make sure that you can access the variables in your `context` dictionary correctly.

You have are rendering a template with a context:

```
context = {0 :['education/Apple.obj','education/Apple.mtl']}
```

You shouldn't use `0` as a context variable name. Change it to something else, e.g. `obj_list`.

From your code, it looks as if you are going to have lots of `<a-entity>` tags, so you actually want a list of lists.

```
context = {}
context['obj_list'] = []
context['obj_list'].append(['education/Apple.obj', 'education/Apple.mtl'])
```

This will give you a context dictionary like:

```
context = {'obj_list' :[['education/Apple.obj','education/Apple.mtl']]}
```

Next, you don't use `context` in the template itself, you use the keys of the context dictionary. In this case you dictionary has a single key `obj_list`, so your loop can be something like:

```
{% for item obj_list %}
    {{ item.0 }}
    {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you have that working, you can start using the variables with the static tag and aframe.

Comment: One last question, You mentioned that I am going to have multiple <a-entity> tags in my Template. That's true, but what if I enter something like "Apple and Strawberry" then my dictionary would look something like this 'dict ={'obj_list':[['apple.obj','apple.mtl'],['strawberry.obj','strawberry.mtl']]}' then can I use item.2 to give me 'strawberry.obj' and If I can't is there another way or a better way of doing so? And if I have multiple keys, what will the for loop look like?

Comment: You can either use `{{ obj_list.1.0 }}` and `{{ obj_list.1.1 }}` to access the values from the second list `['strawberry.obj','strawberry.mtl']`. Or, you can loop through the list with `{% for item in obj_list %}` and use `{{ item.0 }}` and `{{ item.1 }}` inside the loop. On the second loop, `item` will be list `['strawberry.obj','strawberry.mtl']`.